# how can i skip an output result

Tags: php

I want to skip the number 10 so that i only have numbers
from 15 to 5 without outputting number 10.

```
    <?php

    $x = 15;
    while($x >=5) {
    echo "$x <br>"; 
    $x--;
    } 

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `if` condition to ignore `$x` when it is equal to 10:

```
<?php

    $x = 15;
    while($x >=5 ) {
        if($x != 10) echo $x . "<br>"; 
        $x--;
    } 

?>`
```

Comment: @Jozef, welcome to SO. Don't forget to accept the answer if you find it correct and complete.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
    for($i=15;$i>=5;$i--){
       if($i == 10) continue;
       echo $i . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    for($i=15;$i>=5;$i--){
       if($i != 10) echo $i . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: this is the same as the accepted answer except for the reverse logic.  Either answer would get you the same result.

Answer (score 1):

All the other posts are correct, but since you're learning, you should really learn without using shorthand, as it can sometimes be difficult to read.

Not everyone uses shorthand, and in most practices a coding standard is used. Ours in particular doesn't use shorthand.

Example:

```
<?php

$x = 15;
while($x >=5 ) {
    if($x != 10){
        echo $x . "<br />"; 
    }
    $x--;
} 

?>
```

Comment: I agree with this. Gotta walk before you can run.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $num = 15;
   while($num >=5 ) {
    if($num != 10) echo $num . "\n"; 
    $num--;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way without test:

```
$a = array_merge(range(15,11), range(9,5));

foreach($a as $num)
    echo $num . '<br>';
```